# Primitive Dirichlet characters

Tags: number-theory

Take a Dirichlet character modulo $q$ and suppose it has least period $q^*$ when we restrict to $(n,q)=1$.

Why is it true that $q^*|q$?

For $(n,q)=1$ we have $\chi (n+uq^*)=\chi (n)$, for any $u$.

From Bezout's lemma there are $u,v$ for which $$D:=(q^*,q)=uq^*+vq$$ and therefore $$\chi \left (n+D\right )=\chi (n+uq^*).$$Therefore for $(n,q)=1$ we have $\chi (n+D)=\chi (n)$ so $D$ must be a period.  Therefore $q^*\leq D$ implying the result.

Comment: answered myself when writing out carefully...

Comment: Isn't $\chi(n+D)=\chi(n+uq^*+vq)=\chi(n+vq)$ and not the other way around?